# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'DB.jobs' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `jobs`

Tags: php, laravel, mail

Al querer hacer un envío de email me aparece este error:

> ```
> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'DB.jobs' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `jobs` (`queue`, `attempts`, `reserved_at`, `available_at`, `created_at`, `payload`)
> ```

En donde dice **DB.jobs**, reemplacé el nombre de la base de datos por DB mas no es DB.

```
date = new Carbon(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($user->frecuency)));
$samples = $this->getSamples($user->getTemplate, $user->last_send, $user->type_frecuency, $user->frecuency);
Mail::to($user->email)
->later($date, new reporterEmail($samples, $user->getTemplate->format, $user));
```

¿Qué puede estar afectando?

Comment: ¿A qué base de datos estás conectado en ese contexto? El mensaje de error es claro, dice que la tabla `jobs` no existe en esa base de datos.

Comment: Sugiero leas lo siguiente: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues

Comment: Pues si, se me olvido aclarar lo mas importante, esto me funciona correctamente en servidor local, pero al subir los cambios a produccion que es el servidor de amazon es que me muestra ese error

Comment: Y en mi base de datos local no existe la tabla Jobs y aun asi funciona correctamente, nunca me mostró ese error

Comment: No puede ser. Si la base de datos no existe y se intenta esa INSERT saltaría el error. Si no salta una de dos: o la base de datos existe y no lo sabes, o el INSERT no se intenta en el contexto local. Sea como sea, **aquí el error es que intentas insertar registros en una tabla que no existe**. Para que funcione, la tabla debe existir sí o sí.

Comment: Correcto, y es que el INSERT yo no lo ejecuto, de hecho eso pertenece a la tabla jobs que trae Laravel por defecto, de los queue, pero ni idea porque si me funciona correctamente en el local y en el servidor de amazon no.

Comment: Entonces, ¿el problema en concreto cuál es, que no me aclaro? Quizá la cuestión fundamental será leer sobre cómo desplegar correctamente una aplicación creada en Laravel ¿?

Comment: el problema en concreto son los queue que interfieren en el servidor de amazon pero en local no. ese es el problem, ahora que deberia de ver verificar en ese caso?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que está pasando es que en tu localhost estarás trabajando con otro driver ( compara el .env de tu máquina con el .env de amazon )

También debes usar los comandos ( en Amazon )

```
php artisan queue:table

php artisan migrate
```

para crear la base de datos

Comment: y si utilizo php artisan migrate en el sv de amazon no afectaria las demas tablas ? el proyecto no usa migraciones.

Comment: Si no usas migraciones entonces hazlo en tu entorno de desarrollo, exportas la tabla JOBS y luego la importas en Amazon.